# Normally end While LOOP when not found tag in JS iMacros

Tags: loops, while-loop, imacros

```
var i = 1;
var s = "";
while (s !== "#EANF#") {    
    iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:*isBlue* EXTRACT=HREF");
    s = iimGetLastExtract();
    window.alert(i+s);
    i++;
}
```

> BadParameter: expected POS= or POS=Rwhere  is a non-zero integer as parameter 1, line 1 (Error code: -911)

I'm playing around 6 hours and stuck. Why above script can't get extract HREF,

This while only stop work normaly without loop

```
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:*isBlue* EXTRACT=HREF");
```

Plese help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var i = 1;
var s = "";
while (s !== "#EANF#") {   

     iimSet("i",i)
    iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:*isBlue* EXTRACT=HREF");
    s = iimGetLastExtract();
    window.alert(i+s);
    i++;
}
```

Use this code. You forgot iimSet.